# My iPhone's Album Art is Wrong. How can I fix it?

Tags: itunes, album-art

All the art in my iTunes app is wrong. I pay for iTunes Match, but it's disabled on my phone. (It has been enabled in the past.)

What can I do to fix the art?

Comment: if the art is correct on your mac or pc you could try syncing it, or have you tried this already?

Comment: sometimes the album art cache gets messed up. in this case deleting all music on your iPhone, and re-syncing will help.

Comment: I've tried syncing with my Mac. I've since wiped all the music on my iPhone and tried downloading a song again (this time via iTunes Match). No dice.

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot example?

Answer (score 1):

The "awesome" thing is, that if you want to have the right Coverart in your iPhone you are obligated to buy your music in the iTunes store, else it messes the Coverart up (even though it is the correct one in iTunes). Bottomline: neither Amazon mp3 nor imported CD (no matter if original or not) will have the right cover in your iPhone.
Thanks apple for this great new feature !

Comment: I've observed this also, album cover art being replaced by some seemingly general artist artwork.

Comment: "Bottomline: neither Amazon mp3 nor imported CD (no matter if original or not) will have the right cover in your iPhone" I don't think this is correct. I have no problem with any album art on my iPhone and none of my music was purchased from the iTunes Store.

Comment: Sucks when the songs I want aren't even for sale on iTunes /: Have to buy them else where, import them, and then suffer weird album artwork

Answer (score 0):

i know this sounds silly but go into your settings into music and try unchecking "show all music"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a problem with iTunes showing the wrong artwork because you didn't buy the music from them.

It seems like they have artist artwork and album artwork. It makes sense if you have multiple albums by the same artist; which 'album art cover' should it use to represent the artist?

Now if you only have one album for an artist, it does seem a little messed up that they aren't using that cover, especially when you are scrolling through artists and expecting to see that cover.